# TypeError iterating over items in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6, counting

I have a list of dictionaries in which each dictionary also contains a list of items(hobbies).

I am simply wanting to add up how many of each hobby there are and put the results into a new dictionary.

My results should look like: `{'Python': '3', 'cooking': '4', 'reading': '3', ... }`.

The hobby followed by the total number of times it exists.

This is my code:

```
people = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 47, 'hobbies': ['Python', 'cooking', 'reading']},
          {'name': 'Mary', 'age': 16, 'hobbies': ['horses', 'cooking', 'art']},
          {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 14, 'hobbies': ['Python', 'piano', 'cooking']},
          {'name': 'Sally', 'age': 11, 'hobbies': ['biking', 'cooking']},
          {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 54, 'hobbies': ['hiking', 'camping', 'Python', 'chess']},
          {'name': 'Alisa', 'age': 52, 'hobbies': ['camping', 'reading']},
          {'name': 'Megan', 'age': 21, 'hobbies': ['lizards', 'reading']},
          {'name': 'Amanda', 'age': 19, 'hobbies': ['turtles']},
          ]


data = {}
for d in people:
    for hobby in people['hobbies']:
        if hobby not in data:
            data[hobby] = int(1)
        else:
            data[hobby].append(int(1))

for key, value in data.items():
    print(key + ':', end=' ')
    sumvalues = 0
    for elem in value:
        sumvalues += elem
    print(sumvalues)
```

When I run it I get:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Not sure what is generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

On the line...

```
for hobby in people['hobbies']:
```

you are passing the string `'hobbies'` as an index to the list `people`.  Perhaps you intended this instead...

```
for hobby in d['hobbies']:
```

Comment: I actually found that myself a few minutes later, however, the code is still broke.  After I make that change the error changes to:  AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Ignore.  I used Counter() to solve the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

- You probably wanted to get the `'hobbies'` from `d` and not from `people` (which is a list).
- You don't add lists in case there's no entry in your `data` but then try to append to it.

Fixing these it would look like this:

```
people = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 47, 'hobbies': ['Python', 'cooking', 'reading']},
          {'name': 'Mary', 'age': 16, 'hobbies': ['horses', 'cooking', 'art']},
          {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 14, 'hobbies': ['Python', 'piano', 'cooking']},
          {'name': 'Sally', 'age': 11, 'hobbies': ['biking', 'cooking']},
          {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 54, 'hobbies': ['hiking', 'camping', 'Python', 'chess']},
          {'name': 'Alisa', 'age': 52, 'hobbies': ['camping', 'reading']},
          {'name': 'Megan', 'age': 21, 'hobbies': ['lizards', 'reading']},
          {'name': 'Amanda', 'age': 19, 'hobbies': ['turtles']},
          ]

data = {}
for d in people:
    for hobby in d['hobbies']:
        if hobby not in data:
            data[hobby] = [1]
        else:
            data[hobby].append(1)

for key, value in data.items():
    print(key + ':', end=' ')
    sumvalues = 0
    for elem in value:
        sumvalues += elem
    print(sumvalues)
```

However that's a lot of code for something that is already covered (and in a more performant way) by [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
cnts = Counter(hobby for d in people for hobby in d['hobbies'])
for hobby, cnt in cnts.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(hobby, cnt))
```

which prints:

```
Python: 3
cooking: 4
reading: 3
horses: 1
art: 1
piano: 1
biking: 1
hiking: 1
camping: 2
chess: 1
lizards: 1
turtles: 1
```

You can also use the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method of the Counter to get it sorted in descending order:

```
for hobby, cnt in Counter(hobby for d in people for hobby in d['hobbies']).most_common():
    print('{}: {}'.format(hobby, cnt))
```